# ADB pull sdcard returned "failed to copy '/.../.nomedia'..."

Tags: android, adb

I'd like to pull `/sdcard/` folder in my unrooted Android device, so I executed

`adb pull /sdcard`

... and got this error:

`adb: error: failed to copy '/sdcard/Android/data/.nomedia' to '.\sdcard\Android\data\.nomedia': remote open failed: Permission denied`

Anyone knows how to ignore those files, or simply fix this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me answer my own question:

The answer is to zip the folder with tar and pull

```
adb shell "tar czf /data/local/tmp/sdcard.tar.gz -C / storage/emulated/0" ; adb pull /data/local/tmp/sdcard.tar.gz ; adb shell "rm /data/local/tmp/sdcard.tar.gz"
```